Digital filter with maximum removal of harmonics while maximally preserving the other frequencies
I relied on two main themes in my research:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31030/46777

I implemented this filter according to this diagram

to a frequency of 500 Hz and tried to apply a frequency of 500 Hz from the generator to see how it works. The sampling frequency is 2 kHz. If I understood correctly, if "a" tends to 1, then the filter has the narrowest possible band (I got somewhere around 492-508 Hz with "a" = 0.99), and at the same time the minimum suppression of the main frequency of 500 Hz. If I reduce "a", then I will expand the band , but at the same time I will also suppress the signal more strongly at the main frequency of 500 Hz. Is this a correct statement? Also, I did not understand what the coefficient "k" is by which the output signal should be multiplied?

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/80999/46777

As I understand it, this topic is based on the first one, but here it is already possible to delete several harmonics at once. It became even more interesting to me because I can delete all unnecessary harmonics of the signal at once. Moreover, if you look at the graph
, the attenuation occurs more than 60dB, while the remaining frequencies are practically not touched. But I did not understand how to implement it for the microcontroller. Can someone provide a circuit as in the first case? My task is to cut off all harmonics of 1 kHz, 2 kHz ... 24 kHz at a sampling frequency of 48 kHz.
Note: I conducted an experiment and got the following results (I supply a 1 kHz signal from the generator):

In the complete absence of any filters, the signal is 130 units.
If I use 5 2nd order notch filters at frequencies 993-1003; 994-1004; 995-1005; 996-1006; 997-1007. I get a signal of 8 units and a band of +-15 Hz. Yes, I understand that I will need a lot of such filters, 5 for each harmonic, I did it just for the experiment. I also tried to use 1 10th order elliptical filter (995-1005) for each harmonic, but I decided that 5 2nd order filters are better, because they have a faster response speed to changing amplitude. 1 10th order elliptical filter had a very large delay, although it gave me a narrower band of +-5 Hz.
I tried to add only one comb filter as in this thread (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74998/46777) and got a signal of 4-5 units and a bandwidth of +-120Hz.
I did as Dan Boschen described in the answer (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/95278/46777) and got at a=1 I got a signal of 7-8 units and a band of +-60Hz.

Then I tried to decrease "a", but it only widens the band. At a=0.9 the band widened by 2 times to +-240 Hz. I am not sure that "a" can be increased >1, but I tried to increase a=1.01, I got narrowing of the band (to about +-30 Hz), but at the same time some noise was added to the other frequencies (which I want to pass).

//"My task is to cut off all harmonics of 1 kHz, 2 kHz ... 24 kHz at a sampling frequency of 48 kHz."// - - - - - Are you trying to remove all harmonics including the fundamental or are you trying to remove only the harmonics that are the 2nd harmonic, 3rd, 4th, 5th and above?  Do you want this precision-tuned to an arbitrary fundamental frequency?

@robert bristow-johnson I want to remove all harmonics, including the main one. 1 kHz, 2 kHz ... 24 kHz. And do it with minimal impact on other frequencies. My useful signal is in the rest of the spectrum.

Then use a straight comb filter.  Please take a look at the answer I pointed to in the previous comment.  To tune this comb filter precisely, you need a precision delay that can delay by an amount that is not restricted to an integer number of samples.  You will need a precision delay.

@robert bristow-johnson I tried to use a comb filter as in this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74998/46777. It doesn't suit me because in addition to unnecessary frequencies of 1 kHz, 2 kHz, etc., it greatly distorts the shape of the main signal. For me, it would be ideal to have a cut of +-5 Hz, and the rest of the band not change.

Please read my post here, and if you need a delay element that is not an integer number of samples (for precision tuning of the comb fliter), please read the accompanying post.  You want a comb filter that has both feedforward and feedback paths.  You can put the zeros right on the unit circle and their accompanying poles very close.  That will remove only the frequencies at or very close to the teeth of the comb.

The constant $k$ is just a gain scaling and can be set to any value and will adjust the overall gain up and down accordingly.
If you want to reject all the harmonics, assuming they are all submultiples of the sampling rate, then this can be by using the first filter (harmonic nulling filter) given in the second post:
$$H_1(z) = K_1  \frac{1 - z^{-N}}{1-\alpha^N z^{-N}}$$
With
$$K_1 = \frac{1+\alpha^N}{2}$$
And $\alpha<1$ where the closer $\alpha$ is to one, the sharper the null.
This will create nulls at all multiples of $f_s/N$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate. The $z^{-N}$ delay can be replaced with a fractional delay filters to place the harmonic nulling at any frequency, but the simplest implementation is achieved when the sampling rate can be chosen to be an integer multiple of the first harmonics. This is given by $H_1(z)$ as shown in the diagram below with integer delay elements $z^{-N}$. Note is $\alpha$ is close to 1, that $K_1$ will be approximately 1 and may be able to be omitted entirely for a simplest implementation.

For more details on the harmonic nulling filter, please refer to this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/52728/21048
For a demonstration of the first structure shown by the OP on a SAME51 processor along with a detailed explanation (in simplest terms) on how it works, please see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq_SOvR1Sxs&t=137s

Thanks! I'll try to implement it and report the result.

I tried to implement the filter described here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74998/46777. The last picture. I did it like this: My sampling frequency is 48 kHz. The harmonics I want to remove are 1 kHz, 2 kHz, etc. I subtracted z^-48 from the input signal. It works, but it doesn't suit me, because in addition to unnecessary frequencies of 1 kHz, 2 kHz, etc. it greatly distorts the shape of the main signal. For me, it would be ideal to have a cutoff of +-5 Hz (and the maximum possible attenuation in this band), and not change the rest of the band.

@red15530 That's what the purpose of adding the leaky poles as described in this post (which just adds the feedback with a z^-48 with gain coefficient to what you already did), it will flatten the rest of the spectrum (but will add phase distortion so check that that isn't an issue, if so you can do the linear phase compensator I describe in the post you linked but that won't be as flat/sharp as this approach in this post).

I did an experiment and added the results to the question. I like how the filter you suggested works, but I got too big a band of +-60Hz at a=1. Is it possible to somehow narrow the band? Ideally, I want to get +-10-15Hz.

You should not use a=1, a must always be less than 1, the closer a is to 1 without being equal to 1 (for example 0.9999) the narrower the band (but also the longer the delay due to transients-- the bandwidth and response time is an absolute trade with a causal filter). You are going to face a numerical precision issue if you are implementing this in fixed point (and ultimately in floating point as well). The details of that are going to go beyond what we can simply answer here, but email me at boschen at loglin dot com and I may be able to help you further.
